# React-Native File 'expo-module-scripsts/tsconfig.base' not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

my problem is like this

```
// @generated by expo-module-scripts
{
  "extends": "expo-module-scripts/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["**/__mocks__/*", "**/__tests__/*", "**/__stories__/*"]
}
```

desciription
Path to base configuration file to inherit from. Requires TypeScript version 2.1 or later.
File 'expo-module-scripts/tsconfig.base' not found.ts

Comment: `npm install` & restarting vs code fixed this for me

Answer (score 38):

## No need to close VSCode

Just hit `Ctrl + Shift + P` and run `Typescript: Restart TS Server`

Answer (score 35):

I also had this error with another expo module, try restarting vs code and see if the problem is correct.
it worked for me, probably an IDE bug

Comment: You are right.
I restart Visual Studio Code then the issue disappeared

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe the VSCode cant sync the new ts-config file. So in my case I re-opend the VSCode and it worked.

Hope this solution is helpful and sorry about my English not good.

Comment: You can do Ctrl+Shift+P and then type "restart ts server" as well.

Answer (score 2):

my problem solved by install  `types/react-native`

```
yarn add @types/react-native@~0.70.6
```

or

```
 npm install  @types/react-native@~0.70.6
```

it is my package.json:

```
 "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5"
```

tsconfig.js  must like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-native"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try closing and reopening your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this adding a property to 'scripts' in my root package.json, which suddenly disappeared from that in some moment:

```
"ts:check": "tsc"
```

then run:

```
npm run ts:check
```

That command was originally used when creating the project to 'typecheck' it, but it was removed in some installation/deletion of packages in my project.

Comment: I think you made a typo - `npm run tsc:check` should be `npm run ts:check` as `ts:check` is the property added in `"ts:check": "tsc"` - assumng you added it as `{ "scripts": { "ts:check": "tsc" }}`, in the `scripts` top level key in your `packages.json` file. In probably had "run":... as another entry at the same level in `scripts`.

Comment: @NULLpointer yep sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me I had to do all of the above approaches in addition to some extra steps. Let me demonstrate.

1. Check if `tsconfig.base` exists. If it doesn't, you may need to create it.
2. Create `tsconfig.base.json`
3. Create a file named `tsconfig.base.json` in the 'expo' directory if it doesn't exist.
4. The content of `tsconfig.base.json` might look something like this:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
      },
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "expo"],
      "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
    }
```

5. Update `tsconfig.json`. Make sure your main `tsconfig.json` file references the base configuration correctly. It should extend `expo/tsconfig.base`:

```
    {
      "extends": "./expo/tsconfig.base",
      "compilerOptions": {
        // Your project-specific compiler options
      },
      "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
    }
```

6. Check TypeScript version. Ensure that you are using a version of TypeScript that is compatible with the configuration you're trying to use. Update your TypeScript version if necessary:

`npm install typescript@latest --save-dev`

7. Restart the TypeScript Server by performing the command `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` on Windows OR `Command`+`Shift`+`P` on MacOS, then choose the `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`.
8. Close the IDE/Code Editor you had and reopen it.

And Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed such a problem by removing then installing the corresponding module (expo-image-manipulator).
In fact, for some reason, this package is missing its own nodes_modules subfolder.

So, try to execute these commands:

```
yarn remove expo-image-manipulator
yarn add expo-image-manipulator
```